# How to prompt to extend a session?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on an ASP.NET website. I have a page that the user could be working on for some time. It's an extensive form, with file uploading, etc...

I need it to do this: The user has 20 minutes to fill it out and click on save. When 15 minutes has past they get a dialog box, "You have 5 minutes left. Extend session?" If they click "OK" then the "clock" starts over and they get another 20 minutes. If they click "Cancel" OR they ignore the dialog box for more than 5 minutes they are automatically redirected to the Home page. How can I do this exactly?

Comment: So what have you tried? I would probably start a js script timer as soon as the page is loaded, then prompt once 15 minutes is passed. If they click okay, fire off an ajax call to reset their session timeout.

Comment: I was hoping for a code sample/solution that I could easily adapt to my aspx page. I code mostly in vb.net, but I could utilize javascript, jquery, c#, if necessary. Simpler solution the better. Thanks.